# Problema de Ejecución de Función Lambda Para Reiniciar Instancia RDS de Amazon

Tags: python, aws, amazon-rds

Hice una rutina en Python teniendo como base la documentación de Amazon para poder crear una función Lambda con el fin de reiniciar una RDS dada su región más el key y el value de una etiqueta.

La función es la siguiente:

```
# Función para reinicio de RDS

import boto3
import os
import sys
import time
from datetime import datetime, timezone
from time import gmtime, strftime

#REGION: la región en donde se encuentra la RDS
#KEY - VALUE: corresponden a los valores de la etiqueta de la RDS para que la función sepa a         
#cual RDS hay que reiniciar

def reiniciar_rds(): 
region=os.environ['REGION']
key=os.environ['KEY']
value=os.environ['VALUE']

client = boto3.client('rds', region_name=region)
response = client.describe_db_instances()
v_readReplica=[]
for i in response['DBInstances']:
    readReplica=i['ReadReplicaDBInstanceIdentifiers']
    v_readReplica.extend(readReplica)

for i in response['DBInstances']:
#Condición que filtra si la RDS es de Aurora 
    if i['Engine'] not in ['aurora-mysql','aurora-postgresql']:
#Condición que filtra si la instancia es una replica o no.
        if i['DBInstanceIdentifier'] not in v_readReplica and len(i['ReadReplicaDBInstanceIdentifiers']) == 0:
            arn=i['DBInstanceArn']
            resp2=client.list_tags_for_resource(ResourceName=arn)
#Revisa si la etiqueta que pertenece la RDS permite realizarle reinicio
                if 0==len(resp2['TagList']):
                    print('Instancia RDS {0} no coincide etiqueta para operación de reinicio'.format(i['DBInstanceIdentifier']))
                else:
                for tag in resp2['TagList']:
#Si la etiqueta coincide procede a reiniciar la RDS teniendo en cuenta el estado actual de la RDS
                        if tag['Key']==key and tag['Value']==value:
                            if i['DBInstanceStatus'] == 'available':
                                client.reboot_db_instance(DBInstanceIdentifier=i['DBInstanceIdentifier'],ForceFailover=False)
                            print('Reiniciando Instancia RDS {0}'.format(i['DBInstanceIdentifier']))
                        elif i['DBInstanceStatus'] == 'rebooting':
                            print('Instancia RDS {0} ya está reinciándose, por favor espere a que finalice'.format(i['DBInstanceIdentifier']))
                        elif i['DBInstanceStatus'] == 'creating':
                            print('Instancia RDS {0} está en proceso de creación, por favor espere a que se termine el proceso'.format(i['DBInstanceIdentifier']))
                        elif i['DBInstanceStatus'] == 'modifying':
                            print('Instancia RDS {0} está en proceso de modificación, por favor espere a que se termine el proceso'.format(i['DBInstanceIdentifier']))
                        elif i['DBInstanceStatus'] == 'stopped':
                            print('Instancia RDS {0} está detenida'.format(i['DBInstanceIdentifier']))
                        elif i['DBInstanceStatus']=='starting':
                            print('Instancia RDS {0} está iniciando, por favor espere a que termine el proceso'.format(i['DBInstanceIdentifier']))
                        elif i['DBInstanceStatus']=='stopping':
                            print('Instancia RDS {0} está deteniéndose, no puede reiniciarse hasta encenderse nuevamente.'.format(i['DBInstanceIdentifier']))
                    elif tag['Key']!=key and tag['Value']!=value:
                        print('Instancia RDS {0} no existe'.format(i['DBInstanceIdentifier']))
                    elif len(tag['Key']) == 0 or len(tag['Value']) == 0:
                        print('Instancia {0} no existe'.format(i['DBInstanceIdentifier']))
        else:
            print('Instancia RDS {0} está en un estado que impide su reinicio, revise el monitor RDS para más información'.format(i['DBInstanceIdentifier']))

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    reiniciar_rds()
```

Mis variables de entorno son las siguientes:

[image: Variables de Entorno]

Mi evento para pruebas es el siguiente:

[image: Evento]

Y finalmente mi RDS para pruebas está en la región indicada en las varibles de entorno y tiene una etiqueta con los valores necesarios para que funcione el Lambda correctamente. Sin embargo sale este mensaje de error al probar el código:

```
 {
   "errorMessage": "2022-01-12T21:18:24.334Z 2429a912-d5f8-4710-b7d4-441fff4187f5 Task timed out after 3.00 seconds"
 }
```

Con la siguiente llamada de registro:

```
START RequestId: 2429a912-d5f8-4710-b7d4-441fff4187f5 Version: $LATEST
END RequestId: 2429a912-d5f8-4710-b7d4-441fff4187f5
REPORT RequestId: 2429a912-d5f8-4710-b7d4-441fff4187f5  
Duration: 3003.63 ms    
Billed Duration: 3000 ms    
Memory Size: 128 MB 
Max Memory Used: 65 MB  
Init Duration: 251.61 ms    
2022-01-12T21:18:24.334Z 2429a912-d5f8-4710-b7d4-441fff4187f5 
Task timed out after 3.00 seconds
```

¿Me podrían indicar cuál puede ser el problema con mi código? ¿Es algo que debo hacer adicionalmente en la configuración o algo que está mal configurado?

Estoy atento a sus respuestas. De antemano muchas gracias.

Comment: Independientemente del timeout. Se reinician las instancias?

Comment: No. Sale el mensaje de error y no se reinicia nada. En paralelo a la ventana de mi Lambda tengo una ventana con el monitor de RDS y al ejecutar el Lambda y refrescar la ventana del monitor RDS nunca se ve el estado 'rebooting', o sea no está reiniciando nada

Comment: Yo crearía un ambiente local para correr con debug. Lo mas seguro es que este entrando en alguno de los ifs.

Comment: ¿Cómo crearía ese ambiente local? ¿Podrías ampliar tu explicación?

Comment: Instala python con la librería boto3. Crea un par access_key_id y secret_access_key para usarlos en el ambiente local. Con un ide, vscode por ejemplo corres en modo debug y le pones un breakpoint al inicio de la función y te vas paso a paso con step over.

Comment: Entiendo, voy a descargar un ide para realizar dicho ejercicio local y luego te comento cómo me fue

Comment: Por otro lado, dado que python es muy sensible a las tabulaciones, por favor, tabula bien el código

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Por defecto las funciones de lambda sólo duran 3 segundos en ejecución, al pasar esos 3 segundos la función se detiene sin importarle que no haya terminado de ejecutarse por completo. La ejecución de tu código duró 3003.63 ms.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Te recomiendo que aumentes el tiempo de **Timeout** en tu funcion de lambda, eso lo puedes hacer diréctamente en la configuración general de tu función. Te aconsejo colocar el máximo tiempo permitido por aws para la ejecución de una función en lambda que es de 15 minutos para hacer tus pruebas.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Voy a revisar tu sugerencia y te aviso, muchas gracias